# Rerouting to pages is a problem because route can't be replaced

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

==>So I am using 'react-router-dom' and have implemented below routes.

==>say I am on 'http://localhost:3000/About' page and then I navigate to 'http://localhost:3000/Articles/DevOps'.

==>Now if again I wanna go back to About page my url becomes 'http://localhost:3000/Articles/About' however I want it to be 'http://localhost:3000/About'.

Q.why is this '/Articles/DevOps' whole thing not getting replaced?

Code is attached for reference. Thanks

```
<Route  path="/About" component={AboutComponent} />
<Route  path="/Projects" component={ProjectsComponent} />
<Route  path="/IndustryExperience" component={IndustryExperienceComponent} />
<Route  path="/Contact" component={ContactComponent} />
<Route  path="/Resume" component={ResumeComponent} />
<Route  path="/" component={ResumeComponent} />

<Route exact path="/Articles/React" component={AboutComponent} />
<Route exact path="/Articles/DevOps" component={AboutComponent} />
<Route exact path="/Articles/Spring Boot" component={AboutComponent} />
<Route exact path="/Articles/CoreJava" component={AboutComponent} />
___________________________________________________________________________


<Nav.Link href="About">About</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="Projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="IndustryExperience">IndustryExperience</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="Contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link href="Resume">Resume</Nav.Link>
<NavDropdown title="Articles" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
<NavDropdown.Item href="Articles/React">React</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="Articles/DevOps">DevOps</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="Articles/Spring Boot">Spring Boot</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Divider />
<NavDropdown.Item href="Articles/CoreJava">Core Java</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

Comment: I guess these 2 groups of `Route` are in different components(otherwise you would never see `/Articles/React` rendered). can you describe better how is your code structured? and how exactly do you redirect?

Comment: can you share with us the code that redirects you from /Articles/DevOps to /About?

Comment: if you are using Link component for redirecting to the route provided by react-router-dom, can you share it?

Comment: Code is added. All routes are in the same component.There is not redirect code.